# Does cohomology ring determine a compact symmetric space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, symmetric-spaces

Suppose that $M_1, M_2$ are compact connected symmetric spaces with isomorphic integer cohomology rings. Does it follow that $M_1$ is diffeomorphic to $M_2$?

The only result I am aware of is this old paper:

*Wolf, J. A.*, [**Symmetric spaces which are real cohomology spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214428818), J. Differ. Geom. 3, 59-68 (1969). [ZBL0191.20101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.20101).

(specifically, the unnumbered corollary in the introduction) where Joe Wolf proves that each symmetric space which is an integer (co)homology $n$-sphere, is diffeomorphic to $S^n$.

Comment: Related: If $M_1,M_2$ are assumed simply connected and have isomorphic **real** cohomology graded algebras, do you know if they are diffeomorphic?  Here I added simply connected, otherwise we could take $S^2$ vs $P^2(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: @YCor: Good question. Wolf gives one simply-connected example of a real homology sphere $SU(3)/SO(3)$: I am not sure if it is diffeomorphic to $S^5$.

Comment: @Moishe This space is sometimes known as the Wu manifold. Its second homotopy/homology group is $\Bbb Z/2$, and otherwise it has the homology of $S^5$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Thanks! So one has to work over the integers.